# Azure emulator slow with MVC app, can take 120 seconds to register click or JSON call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, azure

Using Visual Studio 2012, Azure SDK 2.1, MVC 4 on Windows 8. Behavior is consistent on Chrome, IE10, IE11, and Firefox.

When debugging the application locally, very often it will slow down or stop responding entirely for minutes at a time. For example, directly entering a route like `https://127.0.0.1:444/Controller/Method/1234` causes...nothing to happen.

Fiddler shows the HTTP request immediately, with an open tunnel to 127.0.0.1:444.

If I'm excessively patient, after 120-240 seconds (!), the breakpoint is hit.

Aborting the connection in Fiddler sometimes leaves zombie requests running; that is, using the same procedure (make the HTTP request, wait 60 seconds, abort the request in Fiddler), 60-180 seconds later the breakpoint gets hit.

This affects more than one application. I think it's something to do with my own configuration, but I can't figure out what settings or issues might be involved.

So far I've tried:

- Turning off Windows firewall
- Toggling the Detect Proxy setting [as this guy suggested](http://www.cloud-developer.eu/blog/2013/10/09/visual-studio-2012-horribly-slow-performance-mvc-4-website-running-azure-emulator/)
- Clearing all cached browser junk
- Stepped through views including shared views

Interestingly, on that last point, sometimes after stepping through all the views...nothing happens for a minute or two before the Controller breakpoint gets hit.

That's a big clue, but I still don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: Update: Sometimes, the controller fires, the shared view completes, and the named view completes...and then nothing. With JSON calls, where no views are involved, request-to-breakpoint can be 60-90 seconds.

Comment: I can confirm that this is a real problem. I have not been able to pinpoint the root cause, but symptoms are the same: server side execution is fast, but browser does not get the answer and waits for two minutes or more. Without Azure emulator all works fine.

Comment: Any updates on this problem?  I'm seeing the same thing

Comment: My project is running extremely slow as well.

Comment: Update: We're now spinning up MSDN virtual machines (A4 size) and developing on those. The machines are completely clean -- nothing on them but Visual Studio and the project, SourceTree, and a couple of tools. On those, the emulator runs perfectly. So now I'm wondering if there's some kind of network blocking going on? Fiddler doesn't show anything though. Other than WireShark, anyone have ideas how we could find out?

Comment: Update: This problem does not occur when running the same project in an MSDN Virtual Machine running on Azure. Those machines are stripped down to the boards, running only the barest minimum services, and they have super-fast network connections (multi-Gb/s). Too many variables to isolate. But at least running the project on an MSDN VM is an adequate workaround for now.

Answer (score -1):

- goto Internet Explorer
- Tools
- Internet Options
- Connections
- LAN Settings
- uncheck “Automatically detect settings”

Found here: [link](http://www.cloud-developer.eu/blog/2013/10/09/visual-studio-2012-horribly-slow-performance-mvc-4-website-running-azure-emulator/)